# Attach a file to a notes document using SSJS

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino, lotus, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to attach a file to notes document, but I am getting the following error.

```
 var doc:NotesDocument = DS_EmpDetails.getDocument();
 var rtitem:NotesRichTextItem = doc.createRichTextItem("AttachmentField");
 var Attachment:String = "C:\\Users\\karthick_m\\Desktop\\PDFIcon.jpg"; 
 var emobj:NotesEmbeddedObject = rtitem.embedObject(NotesEmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", Attachment, null);
 doc.save();
```

I am getting the following error..

```
 [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesRichTextItem.embedObject(number, string, string, string) null
```

Thanks in Advance...

My Stack Trace
**Stack Trace**

javax.faces.FacesException: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:250)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:189)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:154)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:86)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:538)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1140)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:803)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:758)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:527)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1124)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:513)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:342)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:304)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:261)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:291)
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:126)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:365)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1490)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:250)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:189)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:154)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:86)

Comment: please, paste 5-10 lines from stacktrace

Comment: is your file on server? SSJS runs on server, so file you want to attach must be accessible on server - according to "users\..." part of path it seems you have file on client only.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth: My file is on client machine(local desktop). And I am calling this ssjs by clicking on the button from the browser.

Comment: The error is raised because the file is not found from the SSJS code. Are you running a local server or is the XPage running in the Notes Client?

Comment: @SvenHasselbach: I am not running on the local server and the XPage is not running on the Notes Client. I am previewing from web browser(eg. Chrome, not client). I want to attach a file from the current machine in a notes document on a button click in the browser. I know the path of the file. So I tried to attach using SSJS. Where as I don't want to use FileUpload Control in Xpage.

Comment: It is working fine on my client. Do you checked the filepath?

Comment: @Sven: what if RT item exists already?

Comment: @Frantisek: This would cause the error *Script interpreter error, line=2, col=37: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.createRichTextItem(string) null* / In the stack trace you would be informed about the reason: *NotesException: Rich text item AttachmentField already exists*

Answer (score 3):

Use Upload control. The way you use SSJS code is working only for file already on server - you did not upload it.

Comment: In this case it is not required to upload the file.

Comment: Maybe you don't want to, but it is required to upload it. How could it appear in document then?

Comment: The XPage is running in preview mode in browser. If you click the button there, the SSJS code is running locally and can access the local filesystem. That's why *in this case* it is not required to upload the file.

Comment: True. Didn't expect this scenario.

Comment: There is a security issue that we can't upload a local file to a server without the user's interaction/permission.

Answer (score 0):

The error message above may be wrong, but it states that the cause is that the 'rtitem' variable is null.  Have you checked this in your code?

```
if (!rtitem) throw new java.lang.Exception("Uh oh!");
```